# How to alter a postgres datetime column to default to datetime.utcnow

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, datetime, flask

I'm working with flask(sqlalchemy) and postgres, i already declared a model with a datetime column that defaults to `datetime.utcnow()` courtesy of the datetime module in python. however i noticed on new row insertions the time never changes, i did a few digging and found i shouldn't be calling the function but rather passing it thus: `datetime.utcnow`

So, i now wish to alter the column to reflect this change without having to drop the table/column.

I already tried `ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN trans_time SET DEFAULT datetime.utcnow` and i get the following error: `ERROR:  cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression`

Note: I don't have migrations set up for this project so that would not help for now. i only need to do this via sql commands.

Comment: Hi @MikeOrganek, I'm using an ORM(sqlalchemy) and i'm working with flask. My column is the traditional  sqlalchemy datetime column. Here's what the declaration currently looks like: `trans_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())`

Comment: It'd be nice to point out that i already have a working db with no timezone issues at all. So i do not think there's an issue around there.  All i just want is to alter my datetime column to default to `datetime.utcnow` instead of the already existing `datetime.utcnow()`

Answer (score 0):

I would

1. Rename the original table
2. Create a new table with the original table name with the default value as you now want it
3. Populate the new table with data from the original one
4. Drop the old table if everything looks OK.

Hope that works for you. Good luck!